# A "change in scenery" or a "change of scenery"? Are both forms of this sort of expression truly correct? I know the latter one is, but the former?

Tags: expressions, idioms, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-objects

As my title says, is a "change in scenery" as correct as a "change of scenery"? I am self-conscious of how a "change *in*" might sound odd or off or be even absolutely incorrect. Are both forms of this sort of expression truly correct? I know the latter one is (a "change of scenery" makes full sense), but what about the former version of this idea with "in" as its preposition instead of "of"?

Comment: _A change of scenery_ is the one I know as an idiomatic expression. Try Google Ngrams to find out which is the most commonly used.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+change+of+scenery%2Ca+change+in+scenery&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) show the version with **change of** is by far more common

Comment: Brits [still prefer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+change+in+scenery%2Ca+change+of+scenery%2Ca+change+in+scene%2Ca+change+of+scene&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) *a change of **scene***, but we almost all stick with ***of***.